# Codename One parseJSON

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, codenameone, jsonparser

The following Codename One (Java) code runs successfully in the Simulator, but fails on my phone.

Edit: added line numbers

```
    58 Map<String, Object> pageMap = null;
    59 ConnectionRequest connectionRequest = new ConnectionRequest();
    60 connectionRequest.setUrl("https://api.beta.tab.com.au/v1/tab-info-service/racing/dates/today/meetings");
    61 connectionRequest.setPost(false);
    62 connectionRequest.addArgument("jurisdiction", "QLD");
    63 NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueueAndWait(connectionRequest);
    64 try {
    65     Dialog.show("Trace", "pre parseJSON", "OK", "");
    66     pageMap = new JSONParser().parseJSON(new InputStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(connectionRequest.getResponseData()), "UTF-8"));
    67     Dialog.show("Trace", "post parseJSON", "OK", "");
    68     if (pageMap == null) {
    69         Dialog.show("Trace", "pageMap is null!", "OK", "");
    70     } else {
    71         Dialog.show("Trace", "pageMap is NOT null,pageMap," + pageMap.toString().substring(0, 200), "OK", "");
    72     }
    73 } catch (Exception e) {
    74     Dialog.show("Trace", "getPageMap,exception," + e, "OK", "");
    75 }
```

Note: the Trace dialog boxes are my way of getting feedback on what is happening on the phone.

In the simulator, the pageMap is populated and displayed e.g. {meetings=[{meetingName=DOOMBEN, location=QLD, etc.

Edit: clarification

On the phone, the two requested dialog boxes display - (line 65) pre parseJSON and (line 67) post parseJSON. Then (line 68) executes, an exception occurs and the dialog box (line 74) displays: "getPageMap,exception,java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedHashMapEntry java.util.LinkedHashMap.head' on a null object reference".

I believe that, on the phone, the pageMap is not being populated by the call to parseJSON.
Has something changed? (as this worked in a previous build on 16 April 2022).
Can anyone help?

Comment: I can not see any LinkedList in the above code.  Please post the relevant stacktrace

Comment: The third dialog should also show. What does it contain. Also what's the stack trace of the error?
Where does it point to? 
You can connect an android device with a cable and use Logcat to get a stack trace or you can use the Native Logs Reader cn1lib for the same purpose.

Comment: @ShaiAlmog Thanks for the replies. I have edited the question - to include line numbers and clarify the behaviour. Scary Wombat, the LinkedHashMap is in this called source https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/blob/master/CodenameOne/src/com/codename1/io/JSONParser.java (line 562 state = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();). There is no stacktrace. Execution goes directly from line 68 to line 74 (as far as I can tell).

Comment: @ShaiAlmog, I suspected the problem may be some file I have in my local directory. I've just created a new CN1 project in Netbeans, Hello World, with the addition of the lines above. It works in the Simulator, but fails on the phone. If you have time, please try that. The problem appears to be in the call to parseJSON and the return of its data.

Comment: Try removing `pageMap.toString().substring(0, 200)` and see if this works around the issue. It's possible that the map has a null element in it and Android fails on the toString call. That's the only thing I can see here that would fail on that.

Comment: @ShaiAlmog, thanks again. Removing the substring i.e. executing this code Dialog.show("Trace", "pageMap is NOT null", "OK", ""); does work. i.e. that dialog box does display. I did validate the JSON e.g. via https://jsonlint.com/. I'll take a closer look at the content of the JSON (it changes daily) https://api.beta.tab.com.au/v1/tab-info-service/racing/dates/today/meetings?jurisdiction=QLD and see what I can find.

Comment: I think it's a bug in the `toString` implementation of Map on Android. It's valid to have map keys that are null but some developers don't know that and one of them probably worked on the Android code and wrote that bug.